# JQuery fadeIn Delay FadeOut

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fade in a div, keep it on screen for a few seconds then fade it out. The problem is its not staying on screen as long as I expect, even setting the delay for about 10 seconds, it only stay on screen briefly. I've read through many posts and tried many things such as settimeout but I'm going nowhere fast.

Here's my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
    $("[id*=lnkSelect]").live("click", function () {
    var price = $("#price").html($(".prodprice", $(this).closest('tr').prev().children   ('td.prodpricelabel')).html());
    var code = $("#code").html($(".prodcode", $(this).closest('tr').prev().prev().children ('td.prodcodelabel')).html());
    //Build the new HTML
    $(code).prepend("<br/>Item: ");
    $(code).append("<br/>Has been<br/>added to your cart.<br/>Price: ");
    $(".tooltipleft").html(code); //Set the new HTML
    $(".tooltipleft").append(price);
    $(".tooltipleft").fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
    };
</script>
```

So I'm getting the product code and price from the html, modifying the html in the div then fading this in as a notification that an item has been added to the shopping cart.

This is the div that I want to fade in:

```
<div class="tooltipleft" id="tooltip">
    <span id="code"></span><span id="price"></span>
</div>
```

and the button in the grid:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Buttons/add_to_cart.png"
    AlternateText="Add To Cart" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' CommandName="Add"
    ImageAlign="Right" />
```

Comment: This should work as intended. Can you post a fiddle where it doesn't work?

Comment: Works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/265u3/

Comment: click the add to cart button on this web page http://www.t2tuk.co.uk/Items.aspx?Category=4 to see what I mean

Answer (score 22):

do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LJsNG/1/

```
$(function () {
  $('.tooltipleft').fadeIn('slow', function () {
    $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

Comment: There's no problem with this part of the asker's code: http://jsfiddle.net/265u3/

Comment: yes there is. The fadeout doesnt take the delay of 5 sec, mine does

Comment: See my fiddle. The fadeout does take the delay

Answer (score 18):

Use show and hide instead of fadeIn and fadeOut to see if it works. If it doesnt work then your problem is somewhere else.
As you see this working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zceKN/116/) the `$('#foo').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();`
is a correct line of code.

```
$('#tooltipleft').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
```

Comment: `show(0)` will perform no animation. `show('slow')` will perform a different animation than was intended.

Comment: There's no problem with this part of the asker's code: http://jsfiddle.net/265u3/

Comment: I just tired this $('.tooltipleft').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0); its ok but still does not stay on screen for 5 seconds more like 2, so anyreason why this should be?

Comment: This is the web page I have the code on   http://www.t2tuk.co.uk/Items.aspx?Category=4                   currently it is using $('.tooltipleft').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);

Comment: Well you dont see the fadeOut animation because you are refreshing the page. A form is submitted and location.aspx is loaded.

Comment: You're not in the Uk then :-) People in the UK are not directed to the location.aspx. They would see the div displayed, after it disappears the shopping cart contents at the top of the screen is updated, so I figured the post was happening after the div is removed is this incorrect?